# Transaction prediction: Which algorithm?

Tags: pattern-matching, analytics, data-mining, frequency, prediction

I try to predict my spendings for next month. Which algorithm should I dig into?

My guess is to find out regular spendings via frequent pattern detection (FPGrwoth?). I haven't come far with this yet.

My CSV:

[image]

Comment: 3-month average. Done! I would try to keep it simple. You won't be able to predict the exact payments anyway since you might, for example, suddenly buy a flight ticket or pay that yearly insurance invoice.

Answer (score 2):

I like the suggestion from the comments to use three-month average. The approach I'm suggesting below was inspired by that comment (it is in fact a generalization of that).

You could use [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) over the past several months. If `ex[i]` denotes expenses for the `i`-th month before the current one (e.g. `ex[0]` is the current month) and you want to make predictions for the next month, you could do (take care so that weights sum up to 1):

(1/2)*ex[1] + (1/4)*ex[2] + (1/8)*ex[3] + ...

The intuition is that if your spending pattern changes, you should give more heed to the recent months; this is reflected in the weights.

You could of course go with any set of weights that sum up to 1 (e.g. you choose the ones that best reflect how much your spending pattern is likely to change) and take the weighted average according to those weights. For example, you could use

1/4*ex[1] + 1/4*ex[2] + 1/8*ex[3] + 1/8*ex[4] + 1/16*ex[5] + 1/16*ex[6] + 1/16*ex[6] + 1/16*ex[6]

Comment: You can include the same month from last year and give that some weight as well.

Answer (score 1):

FPGrowth solves a different problem: products frequently bought together.

For your "personal finance" needs, you probably can do little more than those (moving) averages along with *seasonality* correction. For example, you will likely spend more time for icecream in summer than in winter (but you'll need multiple years of data).

You can try to do such a seasonality-adjusted moving average (or regression) per common vendor or product type (e.g. ice cream) to improve your results. But these tiny spendings usually won't cause havoc - it's medical bills, buying a new tv or car. But these large spendings are not easily predictable on your buying history alone.